# Is it possible to gen-class with a private final field?

Tags: clojure, private, encapsulation, gen-class

How to create a Java class with a private final field in Clojure?

ClojureDocs for [gen-class](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gen-class) say that `state` field will be public

> :state name
>
> If supplied, a public final instance field with the given name will be
> created.

So, in other words, do we have a way to create a class and after this a java object with the encapsulated state?

Answer (score 0):

@alexmiller answered on this question recently [here](https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/8195/is-it-possible-to-gen-class-with-a-private-final-field?show=8200#a8200)

> In short, no. As you mention in the docs, gen-class state fields will
>   be public final fields. However, that field can be (for example), an
>   atom that is statefully modified by the implementation methods. In
>   general, we do not give much weight to encapsulation in Clojure -
>   instead preferring to make things visible, but "safe" (via
>   immutability). To quote Rich from
>   https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes, "encapsulation is folly".
>
> gen-class is not a general purpose DSL for generating all possible
>   Java classes. It is a tool to generate classes in a certain style in
>   line with Clojure's aesthetics.
>
> Another path however to something along these lines is to use a
>   deftype, which can have private mutable fields, exposed by
>   implementing interfaces or protocols inline. The deftype fields can
>   have meta of either ^:volatile-mutable or ^:unsynchronized-mutable,
>   both of which will become private fields.